# Using append() in javascript to a select form with PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to use javascript to add dynamically an input form.

For example, If I click a button "Add More Fields" it will automatically add another select input form.

When I tried it with my select input form that has PHP code in it. It doesnt work. It gave me an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

PHP / HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="btn btn-primary add_field_button" type="button">Add More Fields</button>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" name="findings[]">
                    <?php 
                        $option = '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->illness.'</option>';
                        foreach($findings->result() as $row)
                        { 
                            echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->illness.'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div> < select class = "form-control"
                    name = "findings[]" > 
                    <?php 
                        foreach($findings->result() as $row)
                        { 
                            echo "<option value="$row->id">$row->illness</option>";
                        }
                    ?> < /select> class="remove_field">Remove</a > < /div>'); / / add input box
                }
            }); $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
```

Comment: "When I tried it with my select input form that has PHP code in it. It doesnt work. It gave me an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token." That's because php doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: @quarterpi Ok. Thanks. I have little knowledge in using PHP with JavaScript.

Comment: No problem. Think of it like this... when the server receives a request for yourpage.php, it looks for php code in that file (everything inside of the <?php ?> tags) and executes it, usually rendering a bunch of html( not necessarily, could be anything) and sends it off to the Client's browser. Now, the client's browser is not fluent in php. It does, however speak html, css, JavaScript, etc. The first thing it renders is the html. Once it has the structure of the page down (which comes from the html) it styles it with css (I know you knew this already... I'm just being verbose;). Next it...

Comment: Renders the JavaScript, which is special because it has the opportunity to do all sorts of fun things, like add in more html or change the styles applied. That is assuming that you place your `<script><\script>` after the `</body>`. If you place it before the body, then it will get executed as soon as the browser comes across it, which can make your page load slowly or even hang depending on the contents of your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented an example for you:

**JS code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
      if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $( ".aaaa" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".input_fields_wrap" );
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if($(".aaaa").length > 1) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
      } else {
        alert('You can not delete all elements');  
      }
    })
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="btn btn-primary add_field_button" type="button">Add More Fields</button>
            <div class="aaaa">
                <select class="form-control" name="findings[]">
                    <option value="a">aaaaaa</option>
                    <option value="b">bbbbbb</option>
                    <option value="c">ccccccc</option>
                </select>
                <button class="remove_field">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you want to use the PHP for the select option than use as below

```
<select class="form-control" name="findings[]">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<?php 
if($findings->result()) {
    foreach($findings->result() as $row) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->illness.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The next challenge is saving the multiple inputs and inserting it to the database.

Comment: Can I use the same classes and javascript to another input form?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add in this way if you want to add more fields which are in the page already you can take a clone by using $("#element").clone() function and then append the same in the place you want